# How to serialize known-classes using Avro without compiling schema

Tags: java, serialization, avro

I'm currently studying Apache AVRO and some points are not clear to me.

Let's say I already have following class:

```
package my.tutorial.avro;

public class MyClass {

private int id;
private String name;

// + Constructors, Getter and Setters
}
```

and following schema:

```
{
   " type " : "record",
   " namespace " : "my.tutorial.avro",
   " name " : "MyClass",
   " fields " : [
      { "name" : " id" , "type" : "int" },
      { "name" : "name" , "type" : "string" }
   ]
}
```

The question is: can I serialize/deserialize data in MyClass format using AVRO but without compiling schema and creating a clone of MyClass?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the Avro Reflect API to annotate your existing class

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks, It really helped a lot!